# Entire Computer crashes when starting Windows 8 phone simulator on Windows 10 (XNA)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, xna

So, a bit of a tricky situation and I'm not sure what's going on honestly.

This game is using XNA and the 2012 refresh of it.

Originally ran Windows 7. Started a WP7 project. Have been working on and off one. Finished 1 year ago. Before finishing, had to upgrade to Windows 8.1 and likewise began using the 8.1 windows phone simulator. Could no longer use VS 2010 and was using 2012 (simulator requires this).

Fast forward to present. Just about finished with an expansion/fix patch so I can forever forget about the game. Currently running Windows 10. Still have VS 2012 and 2010.  Game will not run in VS2010 (expected), however, when running VS 2012 and hitting the 'deploy' button... I get ... rather irritating results.

The Windows virtual machine will show up (the phone case and such saying "OS is booting up"). About 5 seconds it. My whole computer resets. No warning, no 'ding', nothing. It just combusts and restarts.  Any idea why this is happening? My guess is compatability issues, but a flat out system crash is not acceptable... Especially without warning or notification or anything. Could not find anything in system events as well.

Further information: The refresh should in theory work. I have a side project I work on for fun and it is the Windows PC version of XNA. It is not mobile. When I run THAT XNA project, it runs just fine. No issues and certainly no crashes.

Any ideas what this is? or how I can fix it? Downgrading isn't an option for this game, that's just silly.